# How to intercept the request using API-gateway in spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, interceptor

What I am trying to do is:

- I am calling every microservice through API-GATEWAY which is running on 8765 port
- For routing, I already added zuell routes in API-gateway (The calls are running fine)
- I wanted to have an API-key check for every call going through the API-gateway.
  i.e if API-key is blank or incorrect it won't call the other microservice.

Following is my code:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        LOG.info("#### Starting TokenValidateInterceptor.preHandle ####");

        LOG.info("apikeyAttribute-->" + request.getAttribute("apiKey"); //coming as a blank
        LOG.info("apikeyHeader-->" + request.getHeader("apiKey"));//coming as a blank

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(apiKey)) {

            if (!request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/")) {

                try {
                    response.sendError(401, ("Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOG.error("##### IOException occured at TokenValidateInterceptor.preHandle() #####", e);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("##### Generic Exception occured at TokenValidateInterceptor.preHandle() #####,e");
                }
                //This block is getting executed but still its calling the other microservice
                return false;
            } else {

                return true;
            }
        }
```

I am facing 2 problems here
 -

- API-key is coming as null though I am providing it using `postman`
- As I mention I am doing this for a validation check. API-key is coming as blank still it call the respective Microservice

Please see the attach image, 
[The way I am calling my gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Rs7.png)